# Facebook login callback never fired in iOS-SDK v 4.18.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I am implementing Facebook login for my iOS application in Xcode 8.1, with Swift3. The operation is simply done with the following function:

```
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                    fromViewController:self
                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
// my callback logic
 }];
```

(I got this code snippet from the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions). I am not on my work computer right now; because of that, it is obj-c)

I also implemented everything perfectly, regarding `AppDelegate` like methods of the Facebook login SDK, `Info.plist` key-values etc.

When the user has the Facebook app installed, everything works fine.

However, when the user has no Facebook app installed, the callback of the former function is never invoked. `SafaroViewController` shows up, the user logs in and either grants the permissions or rejects the request. And suddenly, `SafariViewController`disappears and my callback does not get called (`AppDelegate` like methods of the Facebook login SDK get called).

What might be the problem?

Comment: Have you set the `facebookLogin` button delegate to this view controller?

Comment: @Karthick, yes. the delegation works perfect, when the Facebook app is installed.

Comment: Okay, from where you designed the button, code or Interface builder?

Comment: It is an UIButton in the `.xib`, and has an UIButton outlet in the `.swift`. And when the button is tapped, i call the `logInWithReadPermissions...` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `FBSDKLoginButton` as the class of your button **instead** of `UIButton` and in your outlet too. Then set the button `delegate` and `permission` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var faceBookLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

// MARK: - View life cycle methods

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Facebook Permissions
    faceBookLoginButton.readPermissions = ["email"]
    faceBookLoginButton.delegate = self
}
```

Thanks:)